# multiple <c:when in <c:choose + cookies

Tags: java, list, jsp, cookies, jstl

hi i am trying to create an ordered list that can display options to move to various pages based on value of cookie. the cookie has been set correctly. and its value is being obtained.. but there is some mistake that i cant quite pinpoint..

```
     <c:forEach items= "${cookie}" var="currentCookie">
    <c:if test="${currentCookie.key eq 'user_type' }">
    <c:set var="user_type" value = "${currentCookie.value.value }"/>
    </c:if>
     </c:forEach>



     <c:choose>
<c:when test="${not empty user_type}">
    <li><a class="" href="#">SELECT</a>
    <ul>
    <c:when test="${user_type='T'}"><li><a href="/myproject/f/auction_history/">My Account</a></li></c:when>
    <c:when test="${user_type='P'}"><li><a href="/myproject/f/auction_history/">My Account</a></li></c:when>
    <c:when test="${user_type='D'}"><li><a href="/myproject/f/menubarCreateAuction/">Create Auction</a></li></c:when>
    <c:when test="${user_type='F'}"><li><a href="/myproject/f/menubarDfoManagement/">DFO Management</a></li></c:when>
    <c:when test="${user_type='S'}"><li><a href="/myproject/f/menubaruserManagement/">User Management</a></li></c:when>
    </ul>
    </li>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
    <li><a class="" href="#">SELECT</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/myproject/f/menubarCreateAuction/">Create Auction</a></li>
        <li><a href="/myproject/f/menubarDfoManagement/">DFO Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="/myproject/f/menubaruserManagement/">User Management</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>

</c:otherwise>
```

the foreach selects various cookies and obtains the one with user_type and obtains the value..

in c choose the value of cookie is compared with predetermined values which generates the ordered list 
if no value is selected then only 3 items should be displayed in the list

pls help..

Comment: your 'test' syntax may need looking at. Try `${user_type eq 'T'}` instead. Note the use of `eq`. You can also use `==`.

Comment: Actually there is a lot more wrong here. Your use of `<li>` and `<ul>` is complete messed up, your embedding of the `<c:when>` statements is wrong, nested without wrapping `<c:choose>` and then your requirement for a sorted list is a bit weird since you'll either have one value or 3, but that is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it.... :D:D:D
the problem was in c:choose.. it was totally uneccessary...
the corrected code is

```
            <c:forEach items= "${cookie}" var="currentCookie">
                        <c:if test="${currentCookie.key eq 'user_type' }">
                            <c:set var="user_type" value = "${currentCookie.value.value }"/>

                        </c:if>
                    </c:forEach> 

      <c:if test="${user_type eq 'T' || user_type eq 'P'}"> 
                             <li><a href="/myproject/f/auction_history/">My Account</a></li>
                    </c:if>                                         
                    <c:if test="${user_type eq 'D'}">
                             <li><a href="/myproject/f/menubarCreateAuction/">Create Auction</a></li>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${user_type eq 'F'}">
                             <li><a href="/myproject/f/menubarDfoManagement/">DFO Management</a></li>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${user_type eq 'S'}">
                             <li><a href="/myproject/f/menubaruserManagement/">User Management</a></li>
                    </c:if>
```

radimpe.. thanks for your input... :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to be fine and will retrieve value of the last occurance of the 'user_type' cookie.

```
<c:forEach items= "${cookie}" var="currentCookie">
    <c:if test="${currentCookie.key eq 'user_type' }">
        <c:set var="user_type" value = "${currentCookie.value.value }"/>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

It should be noted that it will only ever have one value. If you wanted more you'll need to put your 'options' inside the `foreach`.

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${!empty user_type}">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="" href="#">SELECT</a></li>
        <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${user_type eq 'T'}">
                   <li><a href="/myproject/f/auction_history/">My Account</a></li>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${user_type eq 'P'}">
                   <li><a href="/myproject/f/auction_history/">My Account</a></li>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${user_type eq 'D'}">
                   <li><a href="/myproject/f/menubarCreateAuction/">Create Auction</a></li>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${user_type eq 'F'}">
                   <li><a href="/myproject/f/menubarDfoManagement/">DFO Management</a></li>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${user_type eq 'S'}">
                   <li><a href="/myproject/f/menubaruserManagement/">User Management</a></li>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                     <!-- And what if the type is NOT one of your options? -->
                </c:otherwise>
             <c:choose>
       </ul>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
  <ul>
   <li><a class="" href="#">SELECT</a>
   <li><a href="/myproject/f/menubarCreateAuction/">Create Auction</a></li>
   <li><a href="/myproject/f/menubarDfoManagement/">DFO Management</a></li>
   <li><a href="/myproject/f/menubaruserManagement/">User Management</a></li>
  </ul>
</c:otherwise>
```

In the above code, the following changes has been made:

- added a closing `</c:choose>` corrected the use of the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags as this was incorrect
- corrected the `test` statement to use `eq`
- added a nested `<c:choose>` for the conditional options
- added a comment to consider the state of `user_type` being not-empty but also not one of the options provided.

You will need to revisit the flow in your application as I don't think your code will match your requirements.